# Bar plot using logit scale gives error: LogitScale object is not callable

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I am trying to plot a bar plot in matplotlib.
The x values of the plot are of order 10^(-4) which can be plotted using logit scale.
But I am not able to use logit scale by using `plt.xscale()`.

```
plt.figure(dpi=600, figsize=(10, 9)) 
plt.xscale('logit')
plt.bar(x, y, align='center', width=0.8)
```

[image: Error given by compiler]

**Edit**
I tried using

```
matplotlib.scale.register_scale(matplotlib.scale.LogitScale)
```

and it stopped giving the error

Comment: you should use the yscale, you can find good(friendly) instructions here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/pyplots/pyplot_scales.html

Comment: I want the xscale values to be plotted using logit scale. The values on y scale are alright

Comment: what does your import statement look like?  you should be doing import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Comment: Are you using a recent version of matplotlib? Your error doesn't seem to be reproducable.